# Select data where the date is a week before its expire date

Tags: mysql, date

So I'm setting up a query where I need to get items whose going to expire in a week before its expiration date(its expiration date is a month from its creation date)

I'm not really familiar with mysql's date and time functions so I'm not so sure of the syntaxes. Much appreciated ahead of time

EDIT: example, an item is created in feb 20th, its expiration date is march 20th. And lets say today is march 13th, my query needs to get the items whose expiration date is next week.
This is what I'm thinking what it may look like

```
SELECT * FROM ITEMS WHERE NOW() <= DATE_ADD(orders_items.cre_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) - 7 days?
```

Comment: Your question is confusing and lacks code and data. You say at one point that expiration date is a month from creation date and then say you are looking for those with expiration date is a week from creation date. If exp date is month from creation date by definition, then you shouldn't have any that are a week from creation date.

Comment: Your criteria makes no sense as written. If *its expiration date is a month from its creation date*, how can you need to *get items whose creation date is equal to a week before its expiration date*? You just said that expiration date is **a month from creation**, so how can they be **a week apart**?

Comment: sorry guys I just reread my question, was not thinking clearly. Made the edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it the other way around (less complex)
get the items, whom were created 21 days -or more- ago

```
SELECT * FROM orders_items WHERE datediff(NOW() , orders_items.cre_date) >= 21
```

just to explain why 21? it's 3 weeks since create-date which leaves 7 days to expiration date.

you can read more about [datediff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)